# Загрузка div блока на странице

Tags: html, jquery, css

Всем привет. Есть [САЙТ](http://tehnomarket.kz/)
. Проблема в следующем. Внизу есть онлайн конусльтация, работает все хорошо, но если интернет чуть хуже качество то страница загружается след. образом. Сначало Онлайн консультация, все растянуто криво, потом остальные блоки поочереди как и должно быть. Подскажите, как сделать так, что бы загрузились вся разметка, а только потом подгружать онлайн консультацию. Думаю что это поможет,? или есть другой способ?

Answer (score 1):

Ваши скрипты нужно опустить в конец страницы, а не держать их до контента, тогда и контент будет грузится быстрее и не будет возникать таких проблем.

Comment: Так вот именно, что css файл и js грузяться позже, что и приводить, что сначало окно показывается без стилей, во весь экран, а потом когда подгружаются стили он загружается в нормальном виде! Это меньше секунду но всеже заметно!

Comment: ваша страница грузится 9 секунд и 5 секунд при загрузке из кэша.
если ваш сайт грузится дольше 3х секунд, ни один вменяемый заказчик его не примет.
http://www.webpagetest.org/result/151203_K7_V3C/1/details/

Comment: Очень люблю когда на задаваемый вопрос отвечают совсем не по теме.

Comment: @duddeniska это и есть суть проблемы.

Comment: Да нет, разобрался в чем была проблема, параметры стилей в блоке устанавливались в Jquery, а он тем самым ждал загрузки все дока, поэтому и была эта задержка, перевел все в css работает идеально!